# HABTM Relationship With Self?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is it possible to have a has and belongs to many relationship in active record that references the same model?

I want to model a sibling type relationship.

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :siblings
end
```

So far I have created a siblings link table:

```
class CreateSiblings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :siblings do |t|
      t.integer :child1_id
      t.integer :child2_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

But I fear this will lead to me writing ugly code in order to get at the actual instances:

```
siblings = []
child1.siblings.each do |s|
  siblings << s.child2
end
```

I would much rather be able to get an array of children by writing:

```
child1.siblings
```

I am wondering how my link table and model associations should look to support this?

Feel like I am missing something really obvious.

I am on Rails 3.1. Thanks for any help!

Comment: As far as I see, siblings is always like parent.children minus actual child, so to me at first glance this extra table seems unnecessary overhead. At least as long as you don't add further functionality or information. Sure you need this?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, see my comment to Ekampp. In my model children have legal guardians, which they probably will, but not always share with their siblings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1:**

I would simply add a column called something like `parent_id`.

I would then make an instance method on the model, something like:

```
def children
  Model.where({ parent_id: id })
end
```

And if you want the parent you could do something like:

```
def parent
  Model.where({ id: parent_id }).first
end
```

And you can then collect the siblings like this:

```
def siblings
  parent.children.reject{ |r| r == self }
end
```

**Method 2:**

You could also try with the `belongs_to` relation, something like:

```
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Model", foreign_key: :parent_id
```

But I'm not 100 percent sure about this method. You might have to tweak that a bit before it works.

I hope it helps :)

\\ Emil

Comment: That's a neat idea, unfortunately this model has to support split families, so I can't guarantee that 2 siblings will necessarily have a common parent :(

Comment: You could mark them with a `sibling_id` column as well, and then use that to chain siblings together?

Comment: In this case wouldn't each child be limited to one sibling?

Comment: You could add a kind of "AbstractParent" class, which is the parent for  siblings that belong together. (Or reuse the normal Parent class and add a flag and have parent_id and absract_parent_id declared in two belongs_to statements, the second one with :foreign_key). From there on you could still use the structure Ekampp outlines here, which is easier to hadle than a habtm.